# UL Margins- Getting Rid of Them

Tags: css

How do I get rid of the spaces between my images? I would like each image to touch one another. I have tried to set the margins to 0px, but it doesnt seem to do any good.

http://jsfiddle.net/nategines/6EhRZ/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `.thumb li`, you should change `display: inline` to `float: left`. This is the simplest way to remove the horizontal gaps: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6EhRZ/1/

Since we added `float: left`, you'll probably want to contain the floats. Without doing that, this problem happens: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6EhRZ/4/

A quick way to fix that is to add `overflow: hidden` to the `ul`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6EhRZ/5/